# How can I keep text formatted using a QR code?

Tags: yaml, qr-code, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I would like to use a qr code to transmit yaml.
Is there anyway to keep the text formatted when a scanner reads the code?
Where can I read about implementing a custom format for a qr code?

Answer (score 0):

Just include line breaks, tabs and spaces in the text payload, if that's what you mean. You can't force a reader to honor all that when displaying the payload. But you can include it all the same.

Comment: Sean and Terence, thnks for answering the question.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to URL Encode the text before you encode it as a QR code.

Just as the space symbol is encoded as `%20` linebreaks are commonly encoded as `%0A`

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for details.

Generally speaking the JavaScript function `escape()` is good enough for this, although you may want to look at `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()` depending on your needs - see http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm for a good discussion on the differences.

Comment: There is nothing about QR codes that requires URL encoding. If you mean to encode a space character, you just encode a space; encoding "%20" will put "%20" in your QR code. If you're referring to passing the contents to an encoder online, that accepts the contents in a URL -- yes, you'd escape the contents, but this has nothing to do with QR codes per se.

Comment: Indeed - the QR code will happily place any UTF character within the code. But if you're reading the data and \n (or whatever) is being ignored then double encoding it is a potential solution.  As long as you decode it correctly.

Comment: If you've URL encoded it before hand.  For example, if you want to use a USSD command, the hash has to be double encoded. See http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=962

Comment: Sure, but you would have to have a special reader to know that. I assume the OP is talking about readers they don't control, since otherwise there would be no issue getting their reader to do what they like. URL-encoding the YAML will make it not even YAML anymore.